# Capture frames with time delay - iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, camera

I'm trying to write some objective-c code that allows capture of frames through the iPhone camera, after a specific time delay.  Any examples I have found online have captured the 'present' frame input by the camera (i.e. a realtime frame capture).  I am looking for a less real time frame capture - a way to capture frames with a specific time delay.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NSTimer`. 
It would allow you to use the code that captures the current frame, and it would get called after a delay.

You can create a non-repeating timer like this: `timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimerInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(capture) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];` where `delay` is the specific time delay and `capture` is a method that contains the code from an example that captures the present frame.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.....

//call method according to your delay that you need.....

```
    float yourdelay;
    yourdelay = 0.7;
    [self performSelector:@selector(captureView) withObject:nil afterDelay:yourdelay];
```

// or set time for calling method....

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target: self selector:@selector(captureView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

///or you can call method directly when you need..

```
[self captureView];
```

////Here the code for capture real time image.

```
- (void)captureView {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
flickerImaveView.image=viewImage;    
}
```

Hope this will help you....